# how to get controller and action name in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

i just got a quick fix in kohana which is giving a problem,

i have a base class and alot of the classes which extend base class.

all of the classes have after() method, which call the after() method of base class.

now in base class's after() method, i want to record the controller and action name (will add this in D.B)

but how can i get controller and action name in base class.

one way is to modify after() method of each class to pass parameter to parent after() method

or i can get this info from url.

but i am looking for even more automated way, if there is any

Answer (score 15):

The current controller and action can always be called with these lines, also in your base classes:

```
$controller = $this->request->controller();
$action = $this->request->action();
```

Or, if you are in a subrequest:

```
$controller = Request::initial()->controller();
$action = Request::initial()->action();
```